# What is Nidalee's Javelin Toss damage cap?

Tags: league-of-legends

[Nidalee's Javelin Toss](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nidalee) is an ability that deals increased damage the further you are from the enemy it hits **at the time of contact.** This ability is stated to deal 250% damage at maximum range, but sometimes it appears to be more than that.

Is the 250% multiplier a hard cap, such that added distance no longer helps after that point? If this is the case, what is the maximum distance, and is it longer than the base range of the ability?

If 250% isn't a hard cap, what would be Nidalee's maximum damage be at level 1, with starting items, assuming ally help. (i.e. [Thresh's Dark Passage](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Thresh)) on Summoner's Rift

Comment: you trying to do a level 1, one shot?

Comment: It scales very well off AP.  The multiplier is based off a 65% AP, so max would be 162.5% of max AP + some base damage

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a hard cap. Nonetheless Thresh lantern still lets you throw a close range spear for maximum damage.

Comment: you probably already know this, but jumping away in kitty form after throwing a spear can also allow you to do more damage with a non max ranged spear throw. (as long as it connects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nidalee's Spear no longer increases in damage based on distance from Nidalee on impact, it now increases in damage based on distance traveled. The multiplier in the tooltip now accurately depicts the maximum possible damage of the ability.

Answer (score 6):

I quite sure the javelin toss has a hard cap so the max damage would be:

> (55 + 66) * 2.5 = 302.5

66 is the max ability power I could get on level 1(runes, masteries and amplifying tome)

But if there would be no cap I get a max damage of  **799**

using the formula:

> (55+66)*((distance/1500) * 2.5) 
>   Where distance is distance from target on impact.

Thresh is allowed to be **1500** units away from his lantern 
Nidalee's max spear range is **1500** unit

The travel time of the spear is 1500/1300 = 1.15
in this time Nidalee can travel another

> 335 * 1.15 * 1.15 * 1.27 + 400 = **962 units** (Base * Time * Passive * ghost + flash)

So we will get a total of

> 1500 + 1500 + 962 = **3962**

and if we put this in the formula:
(55+66)*((3962/1500) * 2.5) = **799**

if we take Vayne(with a base 30MR) gets hit by this spear
799 - 23% = **615 dmg**

And a lv 1 only has **442 health**.

**CONCLUSION**

If there is no cap on nidalee's spear you could 1 shot an ad carry on LV 1.

Comment: While googling the forums I saw a lot of people saying that javelin has a soft cap, but they don't no how much. So i guess I am wrong about the cap. Does side along Teleport mean: thresh teleporting to somewhere en Nid riding along on the lantarn?

Comment: Why don't you get a few people on a Training Ground custom game and test it out? Remember to do the armor/mr formula.

Comment: You can submit it to riftmyths. its a youtube channel where they test stuff like that

Comment: Don't forget the flash spear technique...SivHD mentions it in his guide to Nidalee. Proving out the 250% are just a limit cause by the range of the skill, but that adding distance to that range increases the damage.

Comment: Is the AP ratio 1 ? :O

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can tell for sure is that around 3 or 4 months ago, there was absolutely no cap on the spear's damage. Using flash to get away right after throwing a max range spear would output a greater amount of damage. I never tried this out since Tresh came out but I know it used to work with flash. SivHD also made a video about Nidalee in which he talks about this "exploit".

Comment: I'm currently at work and cannot access Youtube. I can look into it later (you'll have to wait 5 hours) or you can look it up in SivHD's channel =)